# In Bash, how can I use process substitution to create a template for Pandoc?

Tags: bash, templates, pandoc, process-substitution

I'm trying to modify the default Pandoc LaTeX template (a small setting concerning tables) and I'm trying to do this and the Pandoc run all in one command. I'm getting the error `pandoc: Could not find data file /dev/fd/63.latex` when I try to execute the command and I'm not sure how to address it. The command is as follows:

pandoc --template <(pandoc --print-default-template=latex | sed 's/longtable,//') -f markdown -t latex report.md -o report.pdf

How should I be doing this process substitution?

Comment: The man page says this is a misfeature in pandoc: "If no extension is specified, an extension corresponding to the writer will be added". There doesn't appear to be any way to get pandoc to read a template from an arbitrary filename.

Comment: Use a fifo/pipe which you can name and feed from the substitution? Though that seems much more work than just using an actual file.